# A-frame showing as 3d image in phone instead of WebVR experience

Tags: aframe

framers!

My VR app brings up a 3d photo menu, where I can select what kind of stereographic view works for my app. Some a frame apps (like Mozillas a frame painting app) do show in 3d. How do I ensure that my aframe shows in 3d?

My code is here: [vr-hangman.glitch.me](http://vr-hangman.glitch.me) .

I would post a snippet but no part of the code stands out as having a bug.

When I use Chrome DevTools to fake a phone, I'm getting the error shown in this bug report: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2385

[image: Here is a photo of where the error seems to be occuring]

I've figured out part of the answer, and resolved the bug above. I forked a glitch project to start out with, and it had an old version. However, my app still appears to be incompatible with the Samsung Internet VR experience.

Comment: It needs more ellaboration. Provide code and we will be able to help you.

Comment: I've added my code

Answer (score 0):

So I forked an old A-Frame VR snippet on Glitch, so it was outdated with that bug.

Samsung Internet doesn't support "async function* runGame()" as a snippet. Even though it still updates the display.

Comment: Verify that the official glitch works in your phone / browser: https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: If it does it’s a problem with that code you forked.

Comment: Yeah I actually ran into that problem on some of the examples on aframe. I messaged a dev on the Samsung Internet team, turns out Samsung Internet doesn't yet support async functions